# Cursor disappears when I fullscreen an app on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mouse, 22.04, cursor, fullscreen

When I press F11 on an app like Visual Studio Code, my cursor goes invisible but I can still click stuff. On Firefox, this doesn't happen.

I did a search on Google, but I couldn't find any fixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

1. Open Terminal, and type in `sudo -i` (enter your password if asked)
2. Type `nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
3. Go down to `# WaylandEnable=false`, and remove the `#`
4. Press CTRL + X, and press `Y`.
5. Type `systemctl restart gdm3` and it should work! Make sure to save any unsaved documents before running this command.

Comment: It will be easier to just log out, on the log in screen select an Xorg session, and log back in. Still, nice find that this is an issue related to Wayland, and thanks for giving feedback.

Comment: Yes, but just in case it keeps resetting because of some bug then at least this'll work.

Comment: This is not a fix, this is abandoning the issue by switching from Wayland to XOrg.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently some interaction between the video driver, mutter, and Wayland (see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2657).

It's not really clear from what I can tell who is at fault, but is most likely either Gnome or Wayland.

To workaround the issue, you can do one of the following:

1. Do as suggested above and use X instead of Wayland
2. Change your video driver (the Radeon driver on AMD doesn't have this issue, I believe; not sure about NVidia)
3. Install the Disable Redirect Fullscreen Windows Gnome extension (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1873/disable-unredirect-fullscreen-windows/)

The third solution is I think the easiest and best, provided you don't need the unredirect functionality of Gnome.