# Mouse Curser disappearing in Full screen

Tags: 22.04, fullscreen

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an IMac, and I have a problem with runing games (In this case Minecraft) in full screen (F11) without the cursor disappearing. I have tried to maximize the window by clicking the icon in the top right of the window, but then it doesn't open full screen mode and there's still the dock visible. Another thing I've tried is this:

[Cursor disappears when I fullscreen an app on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433146/cursor-disappears-when-i-fullscreen-an-app-on-ubuntu-22-04)

But that didn't work for me neither as the window actually was in full screen and the cursor was visible, but still, the dock was visible over it.

So, do you have any Idea how to fix this?
Also if you need more information just ask. Thank you!